# Configure shipping for DHL

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, dhl

In Magento_Community_1-7_User_Guide.pdf shipping starts on page 145 (page 155 in PDF). But they do not explain the DHL module.

Where do I find documentation about how and what to configure this?

Also I wounder if this custom shipping calculation is really needed for a simple store or if fix prices do work fine in real life.

I found a [DHL Intership](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dhl-intraship-7494.html) extension that claimes to be the official tool. Is this an addition to the mangeto core function? Does do the same and is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use the DHL extension if you're going to ship through DHL and you want to use their live ship price calculator. Otherwise, you only need to go to System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods -> DHL, and fill in the necessary information. You'll need to get the Access ID, Password, and Account Number from DHL. The rest are personal preferences.